# Sporadic Kernel panic - not syncing

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel

Sometimes, typically in the first minute after booting I get the following error on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS setup:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler
[....] Shutting down cpus with NMI
[....] Kernel Offset: 0xe4000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff
[....] Rebooting in 30 seconds..
```

After that the machine just freezes and never reboots. The PC also has a dual boot setup with windows 10 which never crashes.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo cat /var/log/boot.log` . This might be too long to post here, so use [Ubuntu pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) if you have to.

Comment: that boot log is empty. Is that weird?

Comment: No it's not weird. Instead please run `journalctl --list-boots` the output will list previous boots with a number on the left before each one. Please find a date and time where this issue happened during that boot. Then note the number on the left ( it might look like 0,1,2...etc or with a dash like 0,-1,-2...etc ) use the nubmer as it is with/without a dash in this command directly after `-b` like so `journalctl -b1` or so `journalctl -b-2`  then add the output to [Ubuntu pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and  add the link in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a known bug. Apply the latest kernel with `apt full-upgrade`.

Alternatively, add `processor.max_cstate=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 idle=poll` to the kernel commandline editing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub`, then reboot.

More detail on editing kernel cmdline rules can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/853283

Comment: This appears to have worked. Ran the machine for two days with the kernel settings.